# Which versions of Windows are supported by TeX Live 2021

Tags: texlive, windows, texlive-2020, texlive-2021

[tug. org](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) links  install-tl-windows.exe for installing TeX Live 2021 at  https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-windows.exe.

Which Windows versions are supported by TeX Live 2021?

Can you install TeX Live 2021 in Windows Vista?
Can you install TeX Live 2021 in Windows 7?
Can you install TeX Live 2021 in Windows 8?
Can you install TeX Live 2021 in Windows 8.1?
Can you install TeX Live 2021 in Windows 10?
Can you install TeX Live 2021 in Windows 11?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

[The TeX Live Guide—2021, section 1.2 Operating system support](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-40001.2) says:

> TeX Live contains binaries for many Unix-based platforms, including
> GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, and Cygwin. The included sources can be compiled
> on platforms for which we do not provide binaries.
>
> **As to Windows: Windows 7 and later are supported. Windows Vista may still mostly work, but TeX Live will no longer even install on Windows
> XP or earlier. TeX Live includes no 64-bit executables for Windows,
> but the 32-bit executables should run on 64-bit systems. But see
> https://tug.org/texlive/windows.html for options to add 64-bit
> binaries.**
>
> See section 2.1 for alternate solutions for Windows and Mac OS X.